# How to link a .txt file in .js file using javascript as a language internally?

Tags: javascript, angular

I wish to know how do we link a .txt file to .js javascript file?

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
   var i = `....file`;

  (function(){

   window.onload = (event) =>{


  document.getElementById('javascriptFile') 
          .addEventListener('load', function() { 
          
        var fr = this.fileData(); 
       
       console.log(fr); 
    }) 
   }


  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XHR to fetch the text file directly if you are not using tools like webpack which has loaders to accept txt files

```
fetch('file.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    //filedata
  });
```